# Changes in Lucene Index files when document gets add/update/delete?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, oracle12c

I am working on latest version of Lucene 4.10.2, incorporated with Java as frontend and Oracle 12c as database.

I have indexed one user table having 1 million rows. (Keep LinkedIn user table in mind)

Can anyone explain me what exactly happens to the folder (where files are indexed) when we add document / update document / delete document ?

Attaching a sample image:
[image: Common Lucene Index folder]

I'm trying to understand the file structure of Lucene folder where all indexed files are placed.

This is just one-many relationship structure (we search without logging in), later on I'll move on to many-many relationship (Connections, connection of connection, 1:1 index folder for users).

Let me know if my approach is right/wrong.

Comment: Same question I have..please answer if any body can

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Lucene index consists of multiple "segments". Each segment is only written once, either when you call `commit()`, or when `commit()` is called automatically (by setting IndexWriter to auto-commit when RAM usage reaches a given threshold). Usually when you search an index, each segment is searched sequentially and the results are merged together. The reason that Lucene works this way is because modifying a segment would be a very slow process. Segments can be merged together to improve search performance. [1]

In your example, files beginning with `_0` are the first segment and files beginning with `_1` are the second segment. The `.cfe` and `.cfs` files are "compound files", they contain all of the index files for that segment (sort of like a zip file). See the [file extensions and formats for the default codec](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene40/package-summary.html#file-names) for more information.

So your three operations work like this:

**Add:** Documents will always be added to a new segment.

**Delete:** Deleted documents are not actually removed from the index. Instead, a flag is set to indicate that the document is deleted. Documents that are not deleted are known as "live docs". Deleted documents still influence scoring via the Document Frequency field, and this isn't updated until segments are merged.

**Update:** An update is just an atomic add and delete.

[1] http://blog.trifork.com/2011/11/21/simon-says-optimize-is-bad-for-you/

Comment: Thanks @bcoughlan, that is some explanation :)

Comment: Is it possible to change the name of files Lucene has made @bcoughlan